# Multiply int in array list OCaml

Tags: arrays, ocaml

I'm trying to solve this problem in OCaml:

I have two arrays of variable size like `[1;4;5]` and `[3;2;3]` that represent two integers: 145 and 323.

I would like to multiply this two numbers `145 * 323`. The result is `46835`. I want to have the result in an array `[4;6;8;3;5]`.

Comment: What have you tried, and why doesn't it seem to be working? (As a side comment, it might be more natural to represent 145 as the list [5; 4; 1].)

Comment: I've not any snippet because all my code doesn't work.
I don't know how multiply all single element of first array with al single element of second, and in the end sum all results.

Comment: For StackOverflow to be helpful you need to have a well defined question. You seem to want someone to just write your code for you. Since it's pretty clear this is a school assignment, I don't think that would be fair to other students :-) Figure out some one specific thing you need to know and ask about that (that's my advice anyway).

Comment: @ReimerBehrends No, your comment is useless. Is not a request for homework help. Thanks for your usless answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing math on an integer list is going to cause a headache so the first thing is figuring out how to define the multiplication of two lists. I'm going to assume they will always be integers and define a function as follows.

```
let mult_int_lists a b =
    list_of_int ((int_of_list a) * (int_of_list b));;
```

The function takes two lists, turns them into integers, multiplies them, and then converts that result back into a list. So how do we define `list_of_int` and `int_of_list`? I'd challenge you to figure this out yourself before looking at my code.

```
let int_of_list l =
    let rec exp x = if x = 0 then 1 else 10 * (exp (x - 1)) in
    List.fold_left (+) 0 (List.mapi (fun i x -> x * (exp i)) (List.rev l))
```

Converting a list to an int requires us to reverse the list, multiply each number by 10^i, and then add all of those numbers together. I used List.rev to put the list in order from least to greatest. Then List.mapi takes each value and converts it to the correct tens place. Finally, List.fold_left takes the list of values and adds them into a single integer value.

```
let list_of_int i =
    let rec aux i =
        if i = 0 then [] else (i mod 10) :: aux (i / 10) in
    List.rev (aux i)
```

To convert an int to a list we need to get each tens place by dividing by ten and only keep the remainder. To get the remainder we can use modulus (mod). We can then keep looping until the number equals zero which is when we return the list value. It will be backwards so that is why List.rev is used.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the point of the original homework question (ahem) was for students to implement long multiplication themselves, not to punt the implementation to the standard library. Also, this approach will fail for integers (arguments or result) whose values exceed `max_int`.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is to convert the integers list representing one integer to the integer itself. Use the representation in base 10 of your integers to make a such function. A simple example is for the integer `145 : 100 * 1 + 10 * 4 + 5`. So the first function looks like :

```
   let list_to_int l =
  List.fold_left (fun (acc,n) x ->
     let m = 10. ** (n -. 1.) in
     acc +. x *. m, n -. 1.
    ) (0.0, float_of_int (List.length l)) l
;;
```

I use the function `fold_left` to accumulate the integer value and I use also the function `pow` (remember the base 10).

Second function that you need is to get the digits from an integer. You will have a function like this :

```
        val digits : int -> int list = <fun>
```

With this function (write it as exercice !), you will get the final result. Example :

```
digits 46835;;
- : int list = [4; 6; 8; 3; 5]
```

At the end, you have the following function making the multiplication :

```
let mul l1 l2 =
  let (x1,_) = list_to_int (List.map float_of_int l1)in 
  let (x2,_) = list_to_int (List.map float_of_int l2) in 
  digits ((int_of_float x1) * (int_of_float x2));;
```

You need to convert the integers list to float because the function `pow` works on the type `float`. Hope it helps !